Thunderbird: Smart(er) Searches
I recently migrated to Thunderbird from Apple mail, which I have watched slowly ensh!ttify over the past 20 years. There were hiccups, like zombie rules from iCloud and Thunderbird inventing a "Trash" folder when Apple calls it "Deleted Messages". I think I may have solved these anomalies, but I'm discovering more.
My goal is not quite inbox zero, but better management of something I have let get out of hand. I think I have settled on a workflow, but Thunderbird seems to have artificially less smart searches than I would have expected. For example, I want to create a smart search folder that shows me all messages from Microsoft, no matter what part of the internet, BUT excludes an email address that includes the word microsoft as part of its name but isn't actually microsoft. There is an "ends with" but no "does not end with" term. There is also no "or".
Additionally, I would like to have several smart search folders and then one folder that excludes everything shown in the other smart folders. I can't search a smart search folder!
I think I am at the logical end for this workflow, after hitting some hard stops built into the UI. I tried looking for extensions for stuff like this, but I didn't find anything that looked promising. So now I'm reaching out here to see what I may be missing. If you wanted to leave your inboxes alone, and perform smart searches to categorize your 7000 emails to sort through them for targeted deletion and archiving, how would you go about this yourself?

The add-on Expression Search - NG
seems to answer your criteria.
You will find more information in its
home page on github.
This add-on has the wanted or and not operators in addition
to and. The expressions are written inside the Quick Filter
field:

You may also create with it virtual search folders, as described in
the readme file section
Quick Search Virtual Folder.
If it works correctly for your 7000 emails inbox, it might be
just the tool you need to categorize your emails.

This would be my first time ever using Github for anything but reading, and obviously the first time installing an add-in in Thunderbird. Can you point to a tutorial for this? It's actually hard to cross-reference the process in a search!

I found the same add-on under "Tools" & "Add-ons and Themes". It claims: "This extension adds a new search text box to the end of your quick search bar." However, no such thing happened. This new search text box seems to be the place where all of this add-on's functionality happens, and I can't seem to find it.

I have used this add-on up until a couple of years ago, and it then used the Quick Filter field of Thunderbird. I would try to install its release from its home page on github. I install add-ons by dropping their .xpi file from Explorer into Thunderbird, but you can also do that via Tools > Add-ons and Themes > Tools button > Install Add-on From File...

I appreciate the answer, but I already figured installation out. Right after I installed it, I couldn't find any evidence that anything was there, and that is my current problem. I would like to try out its functionality, but I don't even know if it's there!

I've installed it now myself, and it's still inside the Quick Filter field. Screenshot added to my answer.

Again, I appreciate your reply, but I suppose I have failed to communicate the problem. After installing the extension, I literally had no evidence it exists and I could not test its functionality because I could not confirm that I even successfully installed it.
FINALLY, I noticed a little magnifying glass icon in the extreme lower right hand corner of the Thunderbird window. It appears that I have successfully installed it.
I'm not really impressed by anything it does yet. LOL
